# navigation / button piling effect when user clicks on an option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not sure if this is possible but I have a page with 5 buttons to choose from. This can work like a nav bar in a way. I am wondering if the below is possible using CSS/JS:

- 5 nav/button options displayed
- when user clicks any button, the rest of the buttons appear to be piling on top of the selected button (transition or hidden) so only one button is shown
- when user clicks on the selected button the rest of the buttons/options are displayed

Sorry if this sounds confusing. I have been looking everywhere and can't seem to find any solution for this. Thank you!

My code so far for the html is:

```html
<div class="analytics_buttons">
  <input class="form-btn" type="button" name="btn1" Value="Option 1" />
  <input class="form-btn" type="button" name="btn2" Value="Option 2" />
  <input class="form-btn" type="button" name="btn3" Value="Option 3" />
  <input class="form-btn" type="button" name="btn4" Value="Option 4" />
  <input class="form-btn" type="button" name="btn5" Value="Option 5" />
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Rizowski/Q64yT/

Comment: @mplungjan Yes! that is what I am looking for. I am looking to see if there is a way in addition to this using JS that checks to see which button is clicked and piles the rest of the buttons on top of the selected one. Kind of like a radial menu in terms of functionality/pile effect.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Change class and use tradition

Comment: when changing the class and using transition I will need to edit the JS so to include an is selected statement to determine where to pile the divs correct?

Comment: Please update the question instead of pasting HTML in a comment. I am on my phone and cannot help you with examples

Comment: Set the z-index in a class called top and remove this class from all and add to clicked button

Comment: Pls update your question instead of posting code in comments. I am on mobile so cannot help you right now

Answer (score 0):

Here is one without animation

```js
$(function() {
  $(".form-btn").on("click",function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault(); // stop event if necessary
    $(".form-btn").removeClass("top").toggleClass("stacked");
    $(this).addClass("top");
  });
})
```

```css
.stacked { display: block; position: absolute; left:0px }
.top {
  z-index:9999 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="analytics_buttons">
  <input class="form-btn top" type="button" name="btn1" Value="Option 1" />
  <input class="form-btn" type="button" name="btn2" Value="Option 2" />
  <input class="form-btn" type="button" name="btn3" Value="Option 3" />
  <input class="form-btn" type="button" name="btn4" Value="Option 4" />
  <input class="form-btn" type="button" name="btn5" Value="Option 5" />
</div>
```

Comment: How did you do that.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Dry humor.  Sorry :/

Comment: Ah, I like dry humour just didn't get it in this case.

Comment: You hadn't formatted your example so perhaps you did not grasp the `<>` snippet editor